# Using GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter while camera capturing vs image editing

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I'm a beginner on using GPUImage.
I have noticed that when I apply a `GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter` while capturing and adjusting the `blurRadiusInPixels` and `excludeCircleRadius` using a slider, the filter applied smoothly and there is no significant delay.
However, when I am editing an image and apply the filter with the parameters mentioned, there is a very significant delay processing the image.

Here is my code:

```
...
@IBOutlet weak var photoView: GPUImageView!

var filter: GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter?
var imageSource: GPUImagePicture?
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    photoView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill
    ...
    filter = GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter()
    filter?.aspectRatio = 1
    filter?.addTarget(photoView)

    imageSource = GPUImagePicture(image: image!, smoothlyScaleOutput: true)
    imageSource?.addTarget(filter)
    imageSource?.processImage()
    ...
}
...
// This the callback method when the value of the slider is changed.
@IBAction func updateFilterParameters() {
    filter?.removeAllTargets()
    imageSource?.removeAllTargets()

    filter?.blurRadiusInPixels = CGFloat(blurSlider.value)
    filter?.excludeCircleRadius = CGFloat(focusSlider.value) / 320
    filter?.addTarget(photoView)

    imageSource?.addTarget(filter)
    imageSource?.processImage()
}
```

This view controller is presented when user has already selected an image from the camera roll.

Here is the code opening the said view controller. Take note that this resides from the other view controller:

```
...
var photoEditor: EditorViewController?
...
func openPhotoEditor(image: UIImage?) {
    if image != nil {
        photoEditor = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditorVC") as? EditorViewController
        photoEditor?.image = image!
        photoEditor?.delegate = self
        present(photoEditor!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
...
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: false) {
            self.openPhotoEditor(image: image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How much delay you get for effect ?

Comment: Like 4-8 seconds.

Comment: If you give me your mail id, I will forward my demo you should see this demo

Comment: Run it on simulator'

Answer (score 0):

In `updateFilterParameters()`, there's no need to remove and re-add the targets. Your filter pipeline isn't changing, just the parameters. This is likely causing some slowdown. Rework that method to the following:

```
@IBAction func updateFilterParameters() {
    filter?.blurRadiusInPixels = CGFloat(blurSlider.value)
    filter?.excludeCircleRadius = CGFloat(focusSlider.value) / 320

    imageSource?.processImage()
}
```

As a larger issue, you probably don't want to be processing a full-size image for your live preview if that image is larger than the size of your preview view. I'd recommend using `forceProcessingAtSize` on your first-stage filter to reduce its resolution to the output size in pixels of your preview view. That way, you're only processing the pixels actually being displayed, which can make a huge difference for large images.

You'll need to adjust your blur radius in pixels to be relative to the new reduced size, so that your preview will match your final result, and then when you want to capture your final full-size filtered image for saving to disk you'll want to set `forceProcessingAtSize` back to the native image resolution and re-run the filter process.